# Can I set up Google Assistant to send a push notification to my Android app using Dialogflow?

Tags: android, push-notification, dialogflow-es

Is it possible to set up a conversation using Dialogflow so that when you speak an application specific command to Google Assistant on an Android phone, a push notification is sent to my app without me needing to set up a web server to handle a webhook?

Can the push notification be sent directly from the in-line index.js that you enter on the Dialogflow website under the fulfillment section? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the firebase cloud messaging APIs in your Android App and push that message you want to your app. Please keep in mind that you need some kind of login to connect the push token of your app to your fulfillment code. Without that link you cannot send a push message. If you need more details leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but you could use [Nodemailer](https://community.nodemailer.com/) to send an email from inside your Dialogflow fulfillment. Most Android users get a push notification when they get a new email, which completes half of your goal.

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

// create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://user%40gmail.com:pass@smtp.gmail.com');

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: '"Fred Foo ?" <foo@blurdybloop.com>', // sender address
    to: 'bar@blurdybloop.com, baz@blurdybloop.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello world ?', // plaintext body
    html: '<b>Hello world ?</b>' // html body
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```